# Sizing SVG Background Image

Tags: html, background, svg

Please see the CSS to see how I tried to resize the image. I am not sure how to make The center "content" (the text and the header bar) float on top of the center of the SVG graphic. Is it best to try and center and float the content over the flag background; or would I want to set Box size on the background image? or is there a more simple method to make the content in the center "float" on top of the SVG Flag of myanmar in the background

The url is 
http://morpheus.dce.harvard.edu/~squinn/BlitZEN86/cscie12_assignment2/LAYOUT4.html

(These are my non-working css rules trying to position background and content)

```
.content {
   background-image: url(1000px-Flag_of_Myanmar.svg.png;
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
   padding: 10px 0;
   height:600px;
   overflow: hidden;    
   margin-top:10px;
}
```

Comment: Why do you indent you code like that?

Comment: they wouldnt let me submit question without indenting it

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, SmilingMolecule! When using code examples in your question, you can keep all your indenting intact if you wrap your code with `<pre></pre>` or `<code></code>` tags. There are other methods too, which you can check out at our [Markdown help](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code) page. I hope we can help you solve your question!

Comment: It appears you are using a png picture for your background in your example. Is that the type of picture you are using? If so, you might want to change you question to reflect that, as it might help people in answering your question.

Answer (score 0):

I can't see your URL, but the answer is/was (5 years you get an answer) here: https://www.wonderflags.pro/css-embed

```
.content{
  width:128px;
  height:96px;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;}
  img.wf{background-size:640px 480px;}
  div.wf{display:inline-block;}
  span.wf{display:inline-block;}
  }
```